# Could not synchronize database state with session- Nhibernate and Rebus concurrency issue

Tags: nhibernate, rebus

When using Rebus with Nhibernate, while storing the subscriber details in table getting error like

```
NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener

NHibernate.AdoNet.TooManyRowsAffectedException: Unexpected row count: 5; expected: 1
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.Expectations.BasicExpectation.VerifyOutcomeNonBatched(Int32 rowCount, IDbCommand statement)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.UpdateOrInsert(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Int32[] dirtyFields, Boolean hasDirtyCollection, Object[] oldFields, Object oldVersion, Object obj, Object rowId, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Action.EntityUpdateAction.Execute()
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable)
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list)
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions()
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session)
```

This may happen due to all subscriber concurrency, because If I use debugger, then it work unexpectedly as enough time passes.

Getting exception in this code

```
  public void Insert(ISagaData sagaData, string[] sagaDataPropertyPathsToIndex)
        {
            try
            {
                var nSagaData = new NDbSagaData
                {
                    Id = sagaData.Id,
                    Revision = sagaData.Revision++,
                    Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sagaData, Formatting.Indented, Settings)
                };
                PersistenceManager.Save(nSagaData);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.Error("Insert Exception " + ex.Message);
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText("C:\\TestFolder\\WriteText.txt", "Insert fromSource - " + ex.Message);
                throw new OptimisticLockingException(sagaData, ex);
            }
        }
```

and it says, '**Unexpected row count: 3; expected: 1**'

What will be the reason?

Comment: did you figure out what was wrong with this one?

Comment: @mookid8000 Yes, actually somehow due to coding bug, the GUID are stored multiple times. So it was 3 rows/2 rows. Now solved. thank you.

Comment: It would be nice if you would mark the question as answered then – this way, it is visible that Rebus questions end up getting answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have implemented a saga persister based on NHibernate, and it seems like it has detected a race condition, which I am guessing results in a rolled-back transaction.

I guess the question is *why* a race condition occurred. The "unexpected row count" exception occurs when NHibernate's optimistic concurrency check fails, but in that case I would have expected a message saying "unexpected row count 0; expected 1".

If I were you, I would use Rebus' built-in SQL Server saga persister, as it seems you are serializing the saga data into a single column anyway.